# How do I know run selenium on Android

Tags: python, android, selenium

I have Qpython3L installed on my Android  I have installed the selenium  but I how do I use chrome driver on Android[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zb94W.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's no way to use Selenium for mobile, but you can use Appium. It's compatible with python as well!

http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/mobile-web/#android-mobile-web-automation